# pandas append rows on index with overwrite

Tags: python, pandas

for example, two dataframes are as below

df1

```
index    a     b
  0      1     1
  1      1     1
```

df2

```
index    a     b
  1      2     2
  2      2     2
```

and I want `df1.append(df2)` with overwrite

so result maybe as below

merged df

```
index    a    b
  0      1    1
  1      2    2       <= overwrite value of df2
  2      2    2
```

is there any good way in pandas?

Comment: Then just do `df2 = df1.append(df2)`

Comment: @Zhiya That would create duplicate rows.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using `combine_first`

```
df1=df1.set_index('index')
df2=df2.set_index('index')
df2.combine_first(df1)
Out[279]: 
         a    b
index          
0      1.0  1.0
1      2.0  2.0
2      2.0  2.0
```